# Flutter: Hide tab bar icon on scroll in sliver

Tags: flutter, dart

So here's some example code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: CustomSliverAppbar(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomSliverAppbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomSliverAppbarState createState() => _CustomSliverAppbarState();
}

class _CustomSliverAppbarState extends State<CustomSliverAppbar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text(
                "WhatsApp type sliver appbar",
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              bottom: TabBar(
                  indicatorColor: Colors.black,
        
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.call), text: "Call"),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.call), text: "Call"),
                  ]),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            TabA(),
            const Center(
              child: Text('Display Tab 2',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class TabA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, child) => Divider(
          height: 1,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        itemCount: 30,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I want to do is that when I scroll, the tab bar icon should also disappear leaving only the labels in the tab bar. Currently I have it set to just replace the icon with a container on scroll, but that's a clunky fix and looks horrible since it just instantly disappears on scroll.

So to explain again when I scroll, I want the icon in `Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.call), text: "Call"),` to also disappear, leaving just the call label.

Comment: do you want hide `tabbar` and `appbar` contents on scroll?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it well. In the code above in the tab bar I have 'Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.call), text: "Call"),' From this I just want to hide the icon on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. just change `pinned: true,` to **false** or remove it.
refer `SliverAppBar` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)
refer `NestedScrollView` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html)

```
NestedScrollView(
    floatHeaderSlivers: true,
    headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
      return <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Text(
            "WhatsApp type sliver appbar",
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          floating: false,
          bottom: TabBar(
              indicatorColor: Colors.black,
              labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 16,
              ),
              controller: _tabController,
              tabs: [
                Text("TAB A"),
                Text("TAB B"),
              ]),
        ),
      ];
    },
    body: TabBarView(
      controller: _tabController,
      children: [
        TabA(),
        const Center(
          child: Text(
            'Display Tab 2',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks but this hides the entire tab bar. I'm only looking to hide the tab bar icon.

Comment: Ok you want to hide only tab items not title?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it better. Just want to hide the icon.

Comment: @Runedrune you want to whats app like tab bar?